# share goo.gl url of 404 randomly generated facebook

Tags: facebook, share, goo.gl

I have a problem on random URLs hit on Faceboook account.

After posting a note on http://www.soycarmin.com/, generated a short url with 'google url shortener' and then stick it on the wall account [https://www.facebook.com/pages/Soy-Carmín/1394963147496673](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Soy-Carm%C3%ADn/1394963147496673)

The problem I have is that occasionally brings this url 404.

If the url income I get from goo.gl, it directs me to the site properly ''m carmine' and if I look at the fields 'open graph' these are correctly added.

This causes occasionally have to be debugged my url to share properly.

Could someone help me with this situation?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what the issue is. The Facebook crawler follows different kinds of redirects and you can test if your URLs (and redirects) work by using the [OpenGraph URL debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

Comment: This was solved with the following code ...

$(document).ready(function(){
//Obtenemos la url de la nota de un elemento oculto
var url = $( '#data-url' ).attr( 'data-url' );
getfbcount(url);

//Facebook
function getfbcount(url){
var fblikes;
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, function(data){;
fblikes = data[url].shares;
$(".mod-share-nota-count.likes").text(fblikes);

if (fblikes == undefined) {
$.post('https://graph.facebook.com',{id: url,scrape: true},
function(response){
 console.log(response);
} 
);
}
});
}
});

Comment: If you found a solution, it is better to post it as an answer, because that way you'll be able to properly format it, and other will immediately be able to see what the solution is, as opposed to having to dig though the comments section.